# Input Mismatch Exception

Tags: java, exception, input, mismatch

When I input integer numbers like 5, 7, 14 etc. everything is ok. But when I enter **for example 7.5** I get an error. Where is mistake?

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939) 
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594) 
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564) 
    at Exercise_11.main(Exercise_11.java:8)
```

Below is code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Exercise_11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner radius = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please input the radius of circle: ");
    double r= radius.nextDouble();
    double l= 2*Math.PI*r;
    double s= Math.PI*r*r;
    System.out.println("Length = " + l);
    System.out.println("Area = " + s);
    }
    }
```

[image: input number is 12]

[image: Error with input number 7.5]

Comment: well, above code works for me. If you just put 7.5 it looks like it worked perfectly, as it should

Comment: @APaul no it does not work if I input the double numbers. I add screenshot also you can chek now

Comment: You're working on a system where the locale specifies the `,` is the decimal separator. Try `7,5`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch strange.. The decimal separator on my system is dot "." but I did what you said. It works. Why? Look at 1st screenshot there the system also use dot "." for separating the numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your system's locale is not supporting dot as decimal separator. Use a locale which supports dot as a separator e.g. `Locale.ENGLISH`.

```
Scanner radius = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

**A sample run:**

```
Please input the radius of circle: 7.5
Length = 47.12388980384689
Area = 176.71458676442586
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. Strange.... The decimal separator on my system is dot "." but I did what you said. It works. Why? Look at 1st screenshot there the system also use dot "." for separating the numbers

Comment: Are you setting the locale somewhere in your application like `Locale.setDefault(...)`?

Comment: After your comment I set and it is ok. Working.. But on my computer settings, the separator is not **","**. It is dot **"."** I am sure I use this often.

Comment: Without using my code, execute `System.out.println(radius.locale());` and it will show you what locale your JVM is using by default.

Comment: az_AZ_#Latn .... Understood. Thank you very much. Big appreciate. I learned a lot! Long Live!